# unable to run post-install scripts

Tags: bash, git

After I installed git I saw the following in a dialog, "unable to run post-install scripts". 
Every time I open git bash I see the following on the bash:
`

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/dev/shm': Read-only file system

Creating /dev/shm directory failed.
POSIX semaphores and POSIX shared memory will not work

mkdir: cannot create directory '/dev/mqueue': Read-only file system

Creating /dev/mqueue directory failed.
POSIX message queues will not work

ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/stdin': Read-only file system
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/stdout': Read-only file system
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/stderr': Read-only file system
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/fd': Read-only file system
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/mtab': Permission denied
'C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' -> '/etc/hosts'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/hosts': Permission denied
'C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\protocol' -> '/etc/protocols'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/protocols': Permission denied
'C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\services' -> '/etc/services'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/services': Permission denied
'C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\networks' -> '/etc/networks'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/networks': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/post-install/01-devices.post': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/post-install/03-mtab.post': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/post-install/06-windows-files.post': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/post-install/99-post-install-cleanup.post': Permission denied
```

`
 what might be the problem? 
Will give future hassles, especially while installing packages?

Comment: Was this Cygwin, MinGW, WSL, or something else?

Comment: Note that these post-install things are not part of Git itself, but rather some wrapper around them. This is not an issue with either bash or Git, but rather with your particular distribution.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. The solution was to open Git Bash using the `Run as Administrator` option.

Answer (score 1):

Check first your `%PATH%`.
If you have installed the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), open a CMD and set a simplified path to see if those errors persist when typing in that CMD session "bash":

Type first:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
set GIT_HOME=C:\Path\to\Git
set PATH=%GIT_HOME%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin;%GIT_HOME%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Then:

```
bash
```